# Use Masonry autolayout UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, masonry

I am trying to autoresize table cell with autolayout. But it seems TableView ignores height constraints.

in UItableviewCell：

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

        [self.icon mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(10);
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(10);
        make.width.equalTo(@70);
//            make.height.equalTo(@70);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).with.offset(10);
    }];
  }
}
```

in UITableView

```
XLTableViewCell * _cell = [[XLTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"1"];



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize size = [_cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);

    // size.height is 0.0f;
    return size.height + 1;
}
```

I am trying create an image(70x70) in UITableViewCell. image.top = 10, image.left = 10,image.bottom = 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we do any add Constraints to component with variable height then don't bound it from bottom.Just add some Constant height Constraints and update that constant values.

make.height.constant = some value

and update view Constraints

using one of them

- (void)updateConstraintsIfNeeded NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // Updates the constraints from the bottom up for the view hierarchy rooted at the receiver. UIWindow's implementation creates a layout engine if necessary first.
- (void)updateConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // Override this to adjust your special constraints during a constraints update pass
- (BOOL)needsUpdateConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (void)setNeedsUpdateConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

Comment: `make.height.constant`   constant not found on class MASConstraint.LOL
NICE,`make.height.with.offset(70);` is

Comment: in this there is  view.mas_height instant of  make.height.constant

Comment: i use make.height.with.offset(70); is working. thank you